# Replace the A tag with the any other tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code structure,

```
<a href="sample-test"> Text </a>
```

I am selecting the a using jQuery selector,

```
jQuery('a[href="sample-test"]').css({'backgroundColor' : 'yellow'});
```

and i want to replace the tag with any tag like `<abbr></abbr>`

let me know how to do it using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery('a[href="sample-test"]').replaceWith($('<abbr>' + this.innerHTML + '</abbr>');
```